# JavaFX Button detecting event as well as time elapsed

Tags: time, javafx

I implemented another version of this project with Java `Swing`, but because it could not support multi-touch functionality, I am rewriting it using `JavaFX`.

So I want the program to wait either for a user clicks a `Button` object or for a timeout, say 5 seconds - this means that the program would present a `Button` on the screen at one point and does not proceed to the next phase until either the `Button` is pressed or 5 seconds pass without it being pressed.

Clearly, detecting a click is elementary because adding `ActionEvent` would solve it. The tricky part is measuring the time. When implementing with `Swing` objects, I would have a while loop and have `Thread.sleep(very_short_time_interval)` inside to periodically check the elapsed time:

```
lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ((!pressed) && (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate <= timeout)) {
    Thread.sleep(50);
}
```

The purpose of the `Thread.sleep()` in the pseudo-code above was to prevent the while loop from executing too often. Though it does not seem like the best practice, this trick apparently worked when used with `Swing` objects. But I realized after trying out the same thing with `JavaFX` `Button` objects, it turns the shape of the mouse pointer to a circulating ring, indicating the process is busy on Windows. What is worse is the button would not recognize mouse inputs during this busy phase. I am guessing `JavaFX` objects are heavier than `Swing` objects and is causing this problem as a result.

So my question is, would there be another way, possibly native function in `JavaFX` to make a `Button` expire without requiring a `while` loop? Or would there be some lighter weight objects than `Button` that works in a similar manner (listening to mouse clicks) that could work with the original `while` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `PauseTransition` to wait for n-seconds. On its `setOnFinished` you can add an action to be performed. If the button has been pressed, you can cancel the transition on its action.

```
final PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(5000));
pt.setOnFinished( ( ActionEvent event ) -> {
        doSomething();
});
button.setOnAction( (ActionEvent event) -> {
        doSomething();
        pt.stop(); // If the button has been pressed, stop the Transition
});
pt.play();
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know that existed. I was always using a timer with a delay.

Comment: Yeah definitely sounds like the right tool to use. Thank you.